# Java table in NetBeans's

Tags: java, netbeans

I am trying to code a GUI with NetBeans's GUI Builder. What i want to do is, getting inputs from user via jTextField (done), and using these creating an object (done) and add them to jTable. (that's what i couldn't

Answer (score 1):

You will want to read the JTable tutorial. There you will see that the key to all of this is the JTable's model. You will want to get the model from your JTable, which is likely a DefaultTableModel object, create an array or vector of Object as your row, and pass the row into the model via its `addRow(...)` method. Again, the gory details are to be found in the [JTable Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and the DefaultTableModel API.

Comment: I believe this is the tutorial @HFOE is reffering to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Comment: @MadcoreTom: thanks. I've edited my answer and placed the link in there as well.

Comment: thanx... can u send me a link for the JTable tutorial or code?

Comment: thanx Hovercraft Full Of Eels and MadcoreTom